# How to define the shortcut for selecting to the beginning of line

Tags: xcode, shortcut

When I at the end of line.

[image]

I can use a shortcut to select to the beginning of line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut. If the system-wide shortcut

- <kbd>⌘←</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and
- <kbd>⇧←</kbd> extends the selection it's logically

<kbd>⇧⌘←</kbd>

To discover the shortcuts open the preferences of Xcode > Key Bindings and type something in the search field for example *beginning*

[image]